# Insert a component in a laravel livewire template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to know if there's a way to create a livewire component in where another component can be inserted and declared as a template

e.g.

```php
// /app/Livewire/Button.php
// ...
class Button extends Component {
  public $text;

  public $customIcon; // I want that this be the template

  public function render(){
    return view ('livewire.button');
  }
}
// ...
```

```php
// /resources/views/livewire/button.blade.php
<div>
  <button>
    <div>{{$text}}</div>
    <div>{{$customIcon}}</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

```php
// /resources/views/welcome.blade.php
<html>
  @livewireStyle
  // ...

  @livewire('button', ["text"=>"Submit", "customIcon"=>"<x-carbon-arrow-right class='w-5' />"])

  // ...
  @livewireScripts
</html>
```

To see if there's a better way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just print your `$customIcon` as `html` raw. Try changing your Button component code to this:

```html
<div>
    <button>
        <div>{{$text}}</div>
        <div>{!! $customIcon !!}</div>
    </button>
</div>
```